# AngularJs - GoogleMap : plugin is not defined due to timer?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, cordova-plugins

So I have the version 1.4.0 of the plugin for android.
Every works the first time of loading the app after "cordova run android"
When I close and reopen the app I have the white screen and the log :

```
ReferenceError: plugin is not defined
    at map.js:33
    at angular.js:18744
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5804)
    at angular.js:6081
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13236
```

my map.js where I initialize and use the map

```
$timeout(function () {
            var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
            var ToulousePos = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(43.6040488, 1.4430474000000686);
            var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div, {
                'controls': {
                    'compass': false,
                    'myLocationButton': true,
                    'indoorPicker': false,
                    'zoom': false
                },
...code of the map...
, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an add event on devideReady so it initializes at the right time :

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

and

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
    your function
}